# Place two images inside Text web part with shared vertical coordinates

Tags: image, text-webpart

In a SharePoint modern page, in a single Text web part, I need to be able to place two images side-by-side.  I know this is possible, because I have pages which were migrated from another platform with images that do this.  However, all insertion techniques that I have tried result in the second image below the first (even if one is left-aligned and the other is right-aligned).  Text will flow around left- or right-aligned images, but the images themselves refuse to share vertical coordinates.

Later clarification (with title upgrade): The goal is essentially to get a similar effect to what is nearly trivial in HTML using the `float` attribute: two images which float separately, but which *can* have overlapping vertical coordinates.  (This does not mean overlapping in the sense of one obscuring part of the other.)  They might be on opposite sides of the page, not immediately adjacent. Text should flow around them (otherwise there would be no point to doing this in a Text web part).  In narrow windows, the images might re-flow to no longer share vertical coordinates (although the resizing behavior of images in Text web parts makes it unclear exactly when this would occur).

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to SharePoint, and this may not be what you want, but this is how I did it.
At the bottom of the first section, I added a second section and divided it into two columns.
I added an image into the first column, and a text object into the second column (because I also needed text).  I added my second image into the text column and sized both images until it looked how I wanted it to.
[image]

Comment: You're correct, that isn't what I'm looking for, because I want the text to flow around the images appropriately when window width changes (responsive design).  Since posting the question, I've learned that this is a performance regression that came with SharePoint's switch of CKEditor versions (from v.4 to v.5, I think).  I'm also new to SharePoint, but I now believe that it is currently impossible to achieve what I want.  Unless using the old-style page (which SharePoint confusingly calls a "wiki page"), which work by plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can create a two column text section and add images and text.  When you make the images left or right justified the text fills in.  When you widen the browser or shrink it up, the text flows around the image normally to accomodate.  (I just threw garbage text in, not typing actual words)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm interesting point. It's not what I had in mind, because it requires two unconnected sets of text.  But I think you are right that this is the closest one is able to get in 2023.  It makes me sad that SharePoint lacks capabilities that are baseline-standard in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

cannot you create in Paint one image out of 2? that won't allow the text to go between them but at least it does not take all the space that the 2 columns solution suggests.

Comment: This is of course possible, but does not achieve the goal of the question.  I've edited the original question to try to be clearer about what I mean by "side-by-side".